# Information of Users

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello everybody I am developing an application for android, but I need to get some additional information from the user through your facebook account.

As an example the person's interests;

Using facebook tutorial I managed to do something simple, taking only the basic information of the person, but now I would like to get some more personal information from it. Of course the person has the consent of that.

Good thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Google should be your first place to look. SO is for specific questions.

Comment: I tried but without success.Alias ​​is a matter specifies this particular subject.

Comment: @Kefka I would also go with Simon which particular information you want that should edit it in your question in stead of which "basic information of the person"?. And what you have tried for that is most important.

Comment: Ok, I try google again. Thanks

Comment: you can edit in your question which other basic information you want of the person.

Comment: Actually I wanted the permissions advanced profile. That I would need to access the information such as interests, relationship status and related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer you are looking for is in your facebook permissions string when you begin the authentication process. It has been about a year since I have worked much with the facebook api, so I am sure they have changed things quite a bit. That said, the basic premise is that you get the user's basic information by default, but you will need to request special permission for more complex things, presumably including more details from their profile. You can look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) to see which permissions are necessary for which information. Hope that helps!